# Windows boot volume as read-only?

Tags: windows, iscsi

While it's pretty trivial to mount the boot volume read-only in Linux, I don't think this is possible in Windows. For instance, various logs are written under Windows\system32. You could get around this by mounting a separate writable volume for the sub-directories that get written into, but this already seems overly complicated.

The idea I'm exploring is PXE booting a set of diskless computers from a single read-only install image of Windows accessed via iSCSI.

Can anything like this be done?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "like this". http://strange.systems/windows-xp-booted-via-pxe-and-iscsi-from-read-only-media/ and ["*Enthusiasts have successfully tested and implemented EWF in [..] Windows 10 and Server 2016*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Write_Filter#Resurgence_in_non_embedded_Windows_7_and_versions_since)

Comment: Very cool. Is there any solution to the duplicate name, other than a separate VLAN for each client? I could have a boot script that checks that the current computer name is PC-[MAC addr], or something. If the name differs, as it would on the first boot from the network, the script resets the name and reboots. I would need a small SSD to use as an overlay on each machine which would persist the name change across reboots. This gives me a single central read-only PXE boot image, and requires only a single reboot for a name change on first boot. I wonder if it will actually work...

Answer (score 1):

You explain exactly the **xendesktop** product.

It boot PXE machines from an image in vhd format. So its 1 images for multiple machines.

What the tool do more than a boot is that it can manage KMS activation, to be sure all your diskless pc got an unique activation ID.

Check the doc for more info

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the programs are running server side in this solution with underpowered thin clients. Consider a scenario where most of the desktops are running AutoCAD and Revit, which are graphics and compute intensive. It just isn't feasible for me given these requirements, but it's a neat idea for standard desktops.